# Bash script that defines three processes that have counted the maximum number of bytes from the storage device

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Write a bash script that defines three processes that have counted the maximum number of bytes from the storage device in 1 minute since the script was launched. The script should output the PID, the launch lines and the amount of data read, separated by a colon.

I tried to sum every second a value

```
$(grep "read_bytes:" /proc/$pid/io 2>/dev/null) | awk '{print $2}'
```

for every process and it is always is 0

Comment: Why are you using command substitution? `read_bytes: …` is not a valid command

Comment: Seems like the three processes aren't performing any IO activity that's why the read bytes value for them is always zero

Answer (score 0):

Command substitution is not the correct tool in this case. Command substitution executes the inner command makes its output part of the outer command line.

This means that

```
$(grep "read_bytes:" /proc/$pid/io 2>/dev/null) | awk '{print $2}'
```

will in turn execute

```
read_bytes: 123456 | awk '{print $2}'
```

which is obviously not a valid shell command (unless your system has a binary with name `read_bytes:` in your `PATH`).

You must not use command substitution here and in fact the command will work if your remove it:

```
grep '^read_bytes:' "/proc/$pid/io" 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $2}'
```

(The `awk` part also could be replaced with `| cut -d' ' -f2` or `| cut -c13-`)

---

Alternatively, since you are already using awk, get rid of the separate grep process:

```
awk '/^read_bytes:/{print $2}' "/proc/$pid/io"
```

NB. Quoting parameters is important.